# Java method throwing exception

Tags: java, exception

I have a java method which is potent of throwing multiple unchecked exceptions. My question is: do I need to declare it to throw all the the exceptions or Is there any problem if I declare `throws Exception` only?

Method 1:

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception1,Exception2,Exception3,Exception4,Exception5
{}
```

Instead of method 1, can I declare like this?

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception
{}
```

Comment: If your method throws only `unchecked exceptions`, you don't need any throws clause.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but ideally people choose a specific type of Exception so that you know which type of "Exceptional" behaviour that block of code is having. Exception is superclass - where other ones are subclasses. If you have unchecked exceptions, i.e. your code does behaviour that can be classified within "Unchecked" Exceptional behaviour, you can use `Exceptions` class. but otherwise you need `Checked`ones you mentioned above (may be not all of them).

If you don't understand what different type of exceptions do - try and read this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

This will explain different exceptions and how to use them in your application :)

P.S. For unchecked exceptions, it is *NOT* required to use `throws` in your method signature - but using it possibly don't do any harm - at least you are letting people know that you have "An" exception that may be thrown by this code :) [ I am happy to be criticised for that]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define. But, method caller will loose some information about the exception thrown. Best practise is to throw specific exception and handle them specifically.

Comment: +1, While catching also the same principle applies. Never catch a direct `Exception` which is super of all Exceptions. Always catch specific subclass Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can alway throw the root-exception. If your `Exception1,Exception2,,Exception3,Exception4,Exception5` all extend the same exception somewhere in their heritage-tree you can throw this base-exception.

Be aware that exceptions could have a meaning, i.e. show what can go wrong (and give a hint to handle it). Thats especially important if some other developer has to deal with your method.

Answer (score 0):

If the exceptions are from another functional area or not in your control, I would handle them (by logging, rollback, cleanup of resources, etc.) and wrap them in my own ([Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)) and throw that.