# Does Java declare "throws Exception" by default?

Tags: java, exception

Consider following classes:

```
class X
{
public void met()
   {
   }
}
```

and

```
class Y extends X
{
    public void met() throws NullPointerException
    {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

From what I have read on other questions ( [Why can't overriding methods throw exceptions broader than the overridden method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/why-cant-overriding-methods-throw-exceptions-broader-than-the-overriden-method) and [Java method throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883510/java-method-throwing-exception) )

I understand that the overriding method in the subclass, has to throw either the same or a subclass of the exception thrown in the overridden method.

**Do Java methods always throw at least an exception of the type Exception?**

...In other words the compiler adds *throws Exception*

So the class X would look like this

```
class X {
    public void met() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

**I want to clarify that I am not mistaken** about the fact that the default exception handler Exception is always added.

**Related questions:**

[IOException vs RuntimeException Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416511/ioexception-vs-runtimeexception-java)

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. Note that unless you have a *specific reason* to propagate exceptions up the caller hierarchy (by throwing them), you should probably handle them using catch blocks (or `try-with-resources`)

Comment: `NullPointerException` is a `RuntimeException` and doesn't need a `throws` clause.

Comment: The only type of exception that does not need to be declared is `RuntimeException` and the exceptions that extend it.

Comment: Ok, why is it that the compiler doesn't complain when I override the met method? 

In the super's method I  do not throw any exceptions. The signature has changed in subclass.

Comment: First of all a `class` cant throw exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two types of Exceptions: checked Exceptions (like `ParseException`when parsing text) and unchecked Exceptions (like `NullPointerException`).

Checked Exceptions **must** be declared in the method signature. Unchecked Exceptions **may** be declared in the method signature.

When overriding methods (from an interface or a super class) you only have to specify the exceptions, that you are throwing **in your implementation**. You cannot declare to throw checked exceptions in an implementation that are not allowed in the overridden method.

This is allowed:

```
class X { void someMethod() }
class Y extends X { @Override void someMethod() throws UncheckedException }
```

This is not allowed:

```
class X { void someMethod() }
class Y extends X { @Override void someMethod() throws CheckedException }
```

This is also allowed:

```
class X { void someMethod() throws CheckedException }
class Y extends X { @Override void someMethod() }
```

Comment: The code example was helpful for understanding how it works. I had a previous exercise where the overriding method threw a CheckedException (IOException) when the overridden method did not throw anything at all. Now I understand why. Thank you.

Comment: One code example is the better than many theoretical articles ^_^

Answer (score 3):

What [slartidan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476791/slartidan) said in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30165970/1803692) is fully correct. To explain a little more:

If you are throwing a ["Checked Exception"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1) inside the body of a method, you are required to either handle it (using a catch-block) or to declare a `throws-clause`

To reiterate the previously linked JLS:

1. An Exception is a class **extending** `Throwable`
2. An Error also is a class **extending** `Throwable`

   - Errors usually should not be caught, because they indicate serious problems. (e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`)
   - catching `Exception`  does **not** catch Errors
3. There also is `RuntimeException`. This is a class extending `Exception`

Errors and Runtime Exceptions are **not checked** at **compile time**, because that exactly is what "checked exception" means.

You may throw `Error`s and `RuntimeException`s anywhere in your code.

Now how does this affect throws clauses:

A throws clause specifies that an invocation of the declared method may result in the exception specified. Interestingly throws expects a `Throwable`, which makes following declaration valid:

```
public void method() throws StackOverflowError, NullPointerException {
    //...
}
```

There is no compiler effect when declaring non-checked Exceptions in a throws clause, but it's sometimes done for additional clarity in your sourcecode.

Additionally such Exceptions are sometimes mentioned in JavaDoc (e.g. [`BigInteger#divide`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#divide(java.math.BigInteger)))

But the compiler checks the throws clause when overriding methods. It's somewhat similar to the visibility rules when overriding methods. This means throwing unchecked Exceptions (and declaring corresponding throws clauses) can always be done. Following declaration is valid:

```
public interface Demo {
    void test();
}
public class DemoImpl implements Demo {
    public void test() throws NullPointerException {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

It's the same the other way round. Unchecked exceptions in throws clauses are disregarded by the compiler, because they aren't relevant to compile-time checking:

```
public interface Demo {
    void test() throws NullPointerException;
}
public class DemoImpl implements Demo {
    public void test() {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

The general rule for throws-clause inheritance is: One interface to rule them all: The interface must declare all checked exceptions that can be thrown by implementing classes. Or in other words:

> Implementing classes may declare a subset of the declared checked Exceptions in the interface method's throws-clause in the throws-clause of the implementing method

This means following is valid:

```
public interface Demo {
    void test() throws IOException, ParseException;
}
public class DemoImpl implements Demo {
    public void test() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

What's not valid is declaring a checked exception in the implementing method's throws-clause that's not declared in the corresponding interface method's clause:

```
public interface Fail {
    void test() throws ParseException;
}
public class FailImpl implements Fail {
    public void test() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great elaboration of the answer and a good source of more reading on the matter, especially on checked and unchecked exceptions. I did not know that unchecked exceptions are disregarded at compile-time. Thanks!