# Unreported exception IOException reading file from URL

Tags: java, url, exception, io

I've looked all over SO and have yet to find a solution to this. Long and short of it is I'm trying to take a text file from a provided URL and read it into a String so I can do other things with it.

The specific compile error is:

> ```
> /tmp/java_kWWEO5/Main.java:49: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
>         String text = readUrlTextContent("http://textfiles.com/stories/antcrick.txt");
>                                         ^
> 1 error
> ```

The code causing the error, in `main`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    private static String readUrlTextContent(String url) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {

        URL source = new URL(url);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(source.openStream()));
        try {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append("\n");
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException urlEx) {
            urlEx.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Malformed URL Exception", urlEx);            
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("IO Exception", ioEx);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = readUrlTextContent("http://textfiles.com/stories/antcrick.txt");
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

What could I do to modify this short program so that it finally compiles and executes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Java declare "throws Exception" by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165811/does-java-declare-throws-exception-by-default)

Comment: you can also do `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you actually handle these exceptions in the body of your method by wrapping them into a RuntimeException, your method signature "lies" to the compiler:

> ```
> private static String readUrlTextContent(String url) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
> ```

Change this line to:

```
private static String readUrlTextContent(String url) {
```

That should resolve the compiler message

---

The problem you're experiencing here is that inherent to checked exceptions. When a method declares it throws a certain exception-type, the compiler is **required** to check these exceptions are handled.

This means, even though you correctly catch the exceptions in your method body, the compiler must assume, these exceptions can happen.

Accordingly whenever `reaadUrlTextContent` is called, the compiler checks "Does the caller handle these exceptions?"

If the caller doesn't... well that's what you get :)

What makes your case a little more interesting is that `MalformedURLException` is a subclass of `IOException`. This means whenever you catch (or throw) IOException, a MalformedURLException will be handled in the same way, given it has not been already caught.

Comment: We cannot change the signature of readUrlTextContent() and remove throws IOException, MalformedURLException w/o making appropriate changes in its definition as I have done above.

Comment: @user403348255 you're talking about the "source.openStream()" line, right? If that's the case: mini-codereview - using a try-with-resources block will eliminate the necessity to initialize the BufferedReader with null

Answer (score 1):

Update the signature of readUrlTextContent(String url) as follows:

```
private static String readUrlTextContent(String url) throws IOException{
}
```

And, modify main() as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = null;
    try {
        text = readUrlTextContent("http://textfiles.com/stories/antcrick.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Or only modify readUrlTextContent() as follows:

```
private static String readUrlTextContent(String url) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL source = new URL(url);


            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    source.openStream()));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append("\n");
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException urlEx) {
            urlEx.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Malformed URL Exception", urlEx);
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("IO Exception", ioEx);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(null!=reader)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: while this is completely correct it doesn't explain the **why**